# Outlook 2010 not recognizing HTML table

Tags: html, css, outlook

Outlook 2010 doesn't seem to be recognizing my HTML table in a newsletter email I created. It views perfectly in Gmail with all the correct spacing/padding, but in outlook it just floats the images size by side in one long confusing line of images instead of neatly spaced in the table. I'm somewhat new to HTML so does anyone know if there is an alternative to my table or if something is wrong with my code. Sorry, none of the other similar questions really answered my question

Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="textEdit">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #595959;" valign="top" styleclass=" style_MainText">
            <div style="padding: 0px; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #595959;" valign="top" styleclass=" style_MainText">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;" height="200" vspace="0" border="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.888" hspace="0" width="624" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/888.png" align="left">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;" height="624" vspace="0" border="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.889" hspace="0" width="302" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/889.png" align="left">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;" height="302" vspace="0" border="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.874" hspace="0" width="302" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/874.png" align="right">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;" height="302" vspace="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.881" border="0" hspace="0" width="302" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/881.png" align="right">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;" height="302" vspace="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.882" border="0" hspace="0" width="302" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/882.png" align="left">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;" height="302" vspace="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.873" border="0" hspace="0" width="302" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/873.png" align="right">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 10px 0px 20px 20px;" height="302" vspace="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.884" border="0" hspace="0" width="302" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/884.png" align="left">
                <img style="display: block; padding: 10px 20px 20px 0px;" height="302" vspace="0" name="ACCOUNT.IMAGE.886" border="0" hspace="0" width="302" src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs159/1111545680481/img/886.png" align="right">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This may help you as a template.. https://github.com/dcondrey/Email

Comment: Your problem is that you're relying on 1 DIV for your layout and not a table.
You have one row, and one column.  That's hardly a table layout.  the other problem is that you are relying too much on CSS that Outlook may not support.  The whole reason people use tables is because of the lack of CSS support.

Comment: This may help you https://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/coding/guidelines/

Answer (score 0):

While there are numerous things you could improve with this code the first thing you should do is remove all of the padding styles.  When you attempt to use padding in Outlook, the padding goes haywire... Outlook will copy the padding to every child element and the only thing you can do to prevent it, is to not use padding.

Also, what is styleclass? I've never seen that before and am assuming it's an invalid tag.  Some clients will not render an element if it includes an invalid definition..

Instead of padding use cellspacing, cellpadding, height, width, and empty cells.  You can keep an empty cell from being collapsed by doubling it.  An empty table within an empty table makes the parent table not empty.

This can be used anywhere you might otherwise use a transparent image spacer.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td width="3"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

<!-- same as above properly formatted -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="3">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```